# regex keeps returning false even when regex101 returns match

Tags: regex, dart

I am doing a `list.where` filter:

```dart
        String needleTemp = '';
        final String hayStack =
            [itemCode, itemDesc, itemCodeAlt, itemDescAlt, itemGroup].join(' ');

        for (final k in query.split(" ")) {
          needleTemp = '$needleTemp(?=.*\\Q$k\\E)';
        }

        var re = RegExp(needleTemp);
        return re.hasMatch(hayStack);
```

I printed the output for `needleTemp` and it looks the same as on my regex101 example:
[image]

in dart it prints `(?=.*\Qa/a\E)(?=.*\Qpatro\E)`
basically the same, but nothing matches, not even a simple `letter`.


Is dart regex different or do I need another syntax?

**edit:**

Simple example to test in DartPad:

```dart
void main() {

  print("(?=.*\\Qpatrol\\E)");

  var re = RegExp("(?=.*\\Q2020\\E)");

  print(re.hasMatch('A/A PATROL 2020'));
}
```

still returns false

Comment: Can you clarify what pattern are you trying to match?

Comment: I am just trying to find any letter from any position or direction. but they must be the word itself or part of the word. I think in the picture from regex101 I showed matched the row. I am doing the same thing on another language and it works but in dart it doesn't match.

Comment: "Dart regular expressions have the same syntax and semantics as JavaScript regular expressions." Quoted from [**here**](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/RegExp-class.html). Therefore; positive lookaheads is a zero width identifier and assertion and not a matcher

Comment: I think `\Q\E` is not supported in Dart. If you try to match this `print(re.hasMatch('A/A PATROL \Q2020\E'));` it will pass, so it is matching `\Q` and `\E` literally. https://tio.run/##S0ksKvn/vyw/M0UhNzEzT0NToZqLS0GhoCgzr0RDScPeVk8rJiawILGkKD8nJsZVU0nTGiRfllikUJSqYKsQlJruWlGAUGlkYGSApA5iTlGqXkZisW9iSXKGhrqjvqNCgGNIkL@PAlS5q7omUHXt//8A You can omit it or use word boundaries `\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird right. It doesn't support in `js` either. Isn't it?

Comment: @Mandy8055 Yes, I think so

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I just need to remove `\Q` and `\E` then `RegExp.escape(text_to_escape)` inside the needle.